# fail2ban duplicate log entries

Tags: fail2ban

I am posing this as a question....

It seems every time I restart fail2ban it re-bans all the IP addresses and possibly creates a new log entry for every previous ban.

I pipe every ban to a text file so that I can easily review the bans.

But what I see in the text file is the same IP's that were previously banned entered numerous times.  The confusion is whether the same IP addresses are actually still accessing the server after the initial ban or if these ongoing entries of the same IP are simply copies created every time I restart fail2ban?

Thanks for your reply

Comment: Depending on the ban expiration time, if you still see the IP logged in between the expiration time than your ban is not applying.

Comment: This is my fear.   I'll need to do some research now into checking.  Maybe I can pull up the iptables configurations and look there.  Thanks

Comment: I used the command # iptables -L ....and was able to see that the bans were in place in the chains.  I guess it's the new way f2b handles things on demand.